# Unable to run my node.js on a dedicated server using Phusion Passenger

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger, angular-universal

I'm trying to use `Setup Node.js` cpanel feature to run an Angular SSR app.

I'm getting the following backtrace from passenger.

```
in 'bool Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::checkCurrentState()' (Perform.h:257)
in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::waitUntilSpawningFinished(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)' (Perform.h:213)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::execute()' (Perform.h:1752)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::internalSpawn(const AppPoolOptions&, Passenger::SpawningKit::Config&, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession&, const Passenger::Json::Value&, Passenger::SpawningKit::JourneyStep&)' (DirectSpawner.h:211)
in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (DirectSpawner.h:261)
in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

An here's the location of the problem.

[image]

The following are the problems I'm facing.

- I'm unable to find the passenger log file where I can see the error.
- I'm not sure what is causing the handshake with subprocess to fail.

Maybe someone can give me a pointer on what is causing the problem or how can I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your run method is being triggered.

For this, in the `server.ts` file, make sure you also check `moduleFilename.includes('node-loader.js')` for calling `run()` method. ie

```
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode') || moduleFilename.includes('node-loader.js')) {
  run()
}
```

Or try running this method w/o any condition.

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the problem. Since it was a major time bound issue for us and the support by the company (hosting provider) was not good enough, we decided to drop our hosting plan with them and move onto https://render.com/ which is cheaper and way easier to operate.